# Is there any way to see certain points in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I'm wondering if there is a little bit of code that would do something like highlight a CGPoint, making a dot of some sort on the the CGPoint's location, or if you were using CGRect, to see exactly where the rectangle is on the simulator, not just the numbers in the code.

I'm fully aware that I could just implement my own way of doing this, like using pictures just as labels or drawing a line of some sort, but I was wondering... Is there a built in thing similar to this? Anything that modifies the simulator's view so that you can get more information from it?

Comment: If you only need points relative to the screen, you might just try taking a screen shot and loading it in an image editor.  The simulator has a screen shot option under the File menu, as I recall.  If you need points relative to a view that's not at the upper-left corner of the screen, you're on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to do something like this:

```
- (void) drawRect:(GCRect) rect {
//do my ordinary drawing here

#ifdef DEBUG_DRAWING
// draw whatever I want to visualize some layout I'm doing, 
// typically some NSDrawRect() calls.
#endif
}
```

Comment: I mentioned this in the second paragraph :p I mean I could do this but... I was wondering if there was anything more simple

Comment: What's simpler than calling NSDrawRect()?

Comment: I'm saying like a data type, it would be called something like CGPointMark or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

No built in way that I know of.  A general CGPoint or CGRect has no concept of how it is being used.  On the flip side, there's nothing inherent in a UIView that would do anything to spit out anything visual unless it draws or adds subviews, which of course is implemented by you.

I guess you might need to be more specific and maybe we can think of the easiest way to do it.  Usually when using rect's or points, you're talking about views or layers, so naturally my brain would go towards just writing a quick method to draw a rectangle on the layer...

If it's a point, draw a 1x1 filled rect (it will be close enough to give you an idea of where the point is) and if it's a rect just draw a filled rect with the dimensions.

I'm curious of what you need it for.  I've had an instance where I need the view to record where I clicked my mouse in the simulator, but that's the other way around.

Comment: For the sake of game making, having visuals makes things alot easier to.... visualize.